# Xamarin, how to constantly display current date and time on a label like a digital clock?

Tags: xamarin

Most of the tutorials are with datepickers.  How do i display current date and time in a label. I've googled and all are about date pickers.

Today is "current date + time" .  =Label

Comment: Which part of the question do you need help with? Setting the text on the label? Accessing the current date/time?

Comment: accessing the date and time. i only see option datepicker and timepicker.

Comment: If you type `string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString()`, does it give you an error?

Comment: no it works fine

Comment: @pappenbence96 that's exactly what I was looking for but Jason has better clock, it updates constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a constantly updating time, use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8)

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Start();

private void TimerElapsed(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    myLabel.Text = e.SignalTime.ToString();
}
```

if you want to use databinding, have your elapsed event update the ViewModel property that your label is bound to instead of directly updating the Label

Comment: e only has 4 options Element, Equals, Gethashcode,  ToString.  I added directive System.Timers;

Comment: e is type ElapsedEventArgs?

Comment: my error, syntax error..

Comment: Actually, you cannot use a time in this way. The reason is: Elapsed field is static. That means, you need to make a TimerElapsed() function as static, and then you cannot access from there your UI elements.

Comment: For Xamarin Android you may try to use another approach
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=xamarin-android-sdk-12
/// code  
 static void Main()
   {...
    timer.Elapsed += async ( sender, e ) => await HandleTimer();
...}
   private static Task HandleTimer()
   { ...  }

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (assuming you have a view model with a property of type DateTime called MyDate):

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyDate, StringFormat='Today is {0:MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm}'}" />
```

Output would be something like this:

> Today is July 23, 2019 11:05